# Why multiple pipes in attic?

Tags: attic

I have a single story house, built in the late 40s, with a small kitchen and one small bathroom. I was up in the attic checking something and noticed multiple pipes running to the roof -- all located near the bathroom. I would expect one vent pipe but not sure why there are more.

Water heater and dryer are located in the garage, kitchen stove vents out in another pipe toward the front of the house, house has an old floor heater, so can't think of any obvious reason what these are for.

Anyone have an idea what they might be used for?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Past bathroom remodel?

Comment: From the left - 1st and 3rd could be plumbing vents; 2nd and 4th are more clearly exhausts - perhaps hvac, water heater, etc, or exhaust fan.  Some or all 4 could be leftovers from a remodel and no longer used, of course.

Comment: Thank you both for replying. The house has never been remodeled so still not sure. We have one of those 1940s floor heater that is roughly below where the larger white pipe is. Do you guys know if those types of heaters need to be vented? It looks similar to this:;;    https://images.app.goo.gl/jw16GsYLcTTBvd8F9